# When is maximal analytic continuation a Zariski open set?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, analytic-continuation

I have following question in mind. I apologize if this question is too obvious or naive.

Let $U$ be an Euclidian open set of $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $f:U\to U \times F\subset\mathbb{C}^4$ be an analytic function where $F$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^3$ . What is the maximal Euclidean open set $V\supset{U}$ such that $f$ can be analytically extended to $V$? When is $V$ a Zariski open set in $\mathbb{C}^*$?

Any comments or suggestions on how to think about this question is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You write that both $F,W$ are subsets of $\mathbb C^3$, but then their product is not a subset of $\mathbb C^3$. Are you sure you wrote it correctly? Anyway, I highly doubt there is going to be a nice answer - the maximal extension is going to highly depend on $f$, and often is not unique (consider $\sqrt{z}$ on $\mathbb C$ for an example. I can't think of a condition which would guarantee it is Zariski open outside a relatively trivial case of $f$ being a rational function.

Comment: I have edited now@Wojowu

Comment: Again, now $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$ and $F$ is in $\mathbb C^3$, so their product is in $\mathbb C^4$, not $\mathbb C^3$.